# Почему не увеличивается значение переменной при каждом вызове функции?

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, visual-composer

Искал ответ, ни один из похожих вопросов не помог найти решение.
 Итак, есть кнопка, прямо в верстке навешен `onclick ="showNext()"` ,и такая js функция:

```
function showNext() {
    var step = 1;
    var showBlock = document.getElementById('old-event-hidden-' + step);
    showBlock.style.display = "block";
    function counter() {
        return step++;
    };
    return counter;
};
```

И вопрос: почему событие onclick первый раз работает, а второй - нет?
Надеюсь, как понятно, при нажатии на кнопку - показывает следующий блок по `id`.
Если вдруг это может быть важно - сайт на WordPress, страница создана с помощью плагина visual composer
**P.S.** Обработчик всё же срабатывает, просто значение переменной step почему-то не увеличивается.

Comment: сделайте глобальную видимость переменной для `step`.

Comment: и зачем такое извращение с `counter`?

Comment: @Alex https://learn.javascript.ru/closures

Comment: @Klimenkomud, вот только ты нигде не используешь функцию counter. Самое простое решение - убрать вообще функцию counter, и строку `var step = 1;` вынести из функции `showNext`

Comment: @Alex Под глобальной областью видимости - вы имеете ввиду вынести из тела функции?

Comment: это понятно, но это не ответ на вопрос. если только Вам нужно для собственного понимания.

Comment: @Grundy Оформите свой коммент как ответ, пожалуйста. Ваш совет - правильный ответ)

Comment: глобальная видимость - это когда переменная объявлена вне функции, локальная - когда в функции. ответ на Ваш вопрос "да".

Comment: @Alex, вне _конкретной_ функции не всегда значит _глобально_

Comment: @Grundy подразумевалось вне конструкции function, а не конкретной функции. Хорошее уточнение, спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При клике - каждый раз вызывается `showNext()`, следовательно - каждый раз step инициализируется единицей, поэтому всегда обращение идет только к одному элементу.

Возвращаемая функция `counter` никем не используется, поэтому ее можно просто убрать.

Чтобы значение step изменялось, его надо хранить *вне* данной функции, для этого можно вынести строку инициализации

```
var step = 1;
```

за пределы функции `showNext()`

Тогда получится так:

```
var step = 1;
function showNext() {
    var showBlock = document.getElementById('old-event-hidden-' + step);
    showBlock.style.display = "block";
    step = step + 1; // увеличиваем значение счетчика для следующего вызова
};
```

Либо можно вынести наружу функцию counter:

```
var counter = function(){
    var step = 1;
    function counter() {
        return step++;
    };
    return counter;
}

function showNext() {
    var showBlock = document.getElementById('old-event-hidden-' + counter());
    showBlock.style.display = "block";
};
```

Либо можно навешивать обработчик через js

```
button.onclick = function showNext() {
    var step = 1;
    function counter() {
        var showBlock = document.getElementById('old-event-hidden-' + step);
        showBlock.style.display = "block";
        step++;
    };
    return counter;
}();
```

или

```
button.addEventListener('click',function showNext() {
    var step = 1;
    function counter() {
        var showBlock = document.getElementById('old-event-hidden-' + step);
        showBlock.style.display = "block";
        step++;
    };
    return counter;
}());
```

Comment: Спасибо большое =)

Answer (score 1):

Она срабатывает столько раз, сколько нужно. Просто у тебя в каждом вызове `showNext` своя переменная `step`, имеющая значение 1.

Comment: Хорошо, тогда как мне инкрементировать его? В коде вроде как видна попытка этого действия, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Дополнил вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

```
var showBlock = document.getElementById('old-event-hidden-' + step);
```

Ищет элемент с классом old-event-hidden-1

```
 function counter() {
        return step++;
    };
    return counter;
```

Запускается функция counter() и происходит выход из самой функции showNext() и всё внутри это функции, обнуляется.

Comment: Вы имели ввиду элемент с `id`? Это ведь вложенная функция, он не может выйти из корневой по первому `return`

Comment: в данном коде никакая функция counter не запускается